# JWT Token Wont Update when using dagger 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have problem using dagger 2 for updating token in runtime.

So here is the scenario:

I have a screen to Change Password. when i succeed update password, the current jwt token would be invalid, and i need to store new token from update token response, i store that token in SharedPreferences. but the problem is when i store the token. it updated in sharedprefernces, but wont update value in DaggerGraph where i build Retrofit instance (Authorization header).

Below is my code :

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [StorageModule::class, AppModule::class, ViewModelModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: SplashActivity)

    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

    fun inject(activity: ChangePasswordActivity)
}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthInterceptor(sharedPreferencesSources: SharedPreferencesSources): Interceptor {
        return AuthInterceptor(sharedPreferencesSources.tokenApi())
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(
        authInterceptor: Interceptor
    ): SharedProductClient {
        return Network.retrofitClient(authInterceptor = authInterceptor)
            .create(SharedProductClient::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppRepository(apiService: SharedProductClient): AppRepository {
        return AppRepositoryImpl(apiService)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppUseCase(appRepository: AppRepository): AppUseCase {
        return AppUseCase(appRepository)
    }
   
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAppScheduler(): SchedulerProvider = AppSchedulerProvider()
}
```

**StorageModule.kt**

```
@Module
class StorageModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferencesSource(sharedPrefInstance: SharedPreferences): SharedPreferencesSources {
        return SharedPreferencesSourcesImpl(sharedPrefInstance)
    }

    companion object {
        const val SharedPrefName = "share_product_prefs"
    }
}
```

**AuthInterceptor.kt**

```
class AuthInterceptor constructor(
    private val token: String
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be really help me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put where your trying to override token in shard preference.

Comment: hai, i put sharedpreferennces in a interface with its implementation. and provide its interface in **StorageModule.kt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you only pass a `String` instance of the token when creating the `AuthInterceptor`.

You should provide a way (e.g. an interface) of dynamically obtaining the token from the `SharedPreferences` when needed.

---

This is one way of doing this:

1. Change the `token:String` to a function type in your `AuthInterceptor` constructor (and use it when needed):

```
class AuthInterceptor constructor(
    private val tokenProvider: () -> String
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${tokenProvider.invoke()}")
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

2. When creating your `AuthInteceptor` build your lambda to dynamically refer to `SharedPreferences`

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthInterceptor(sharedPreferencesSources: SharedPreferencesSources): Interceptor {
        return AuthInterceptor(){ sharedPreferencesSources.tokenApi() }
    }

    //...
}
```

This way the `tokenProvider` will be `invoked` (`SharedPreferences` will be accessed) every time you make an api call, instead of just a single time when creating the `AuthInterceptor`.